# Is google's Firebase is efficient for apps like alibaba?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

As Firebase chrges are less compared to parse, is it makes sense to use Firebase for apps like Alibaba, Olx, Quicker?

How to fetch ads posted 100km's around me? based on lat long data stored in table.

How efficient is firebase for above usecases?

How complex data structures and relations are created in Firebase?

structures like

```
 [
 {
"salelead_id": 1,
"salelead_user_id": 2,
"salelead_post_date": "12-2-1500",
"salelead_offer_start": "12-2-1500",
"salelead_offer_end": "12-2-1500",
"salelead_loc_lat": 12,
"salelead_loc_long": 12,
"salelead_details": {
  "sid": 0,    <-----    primery key of sale table
  "user_id": 0,  <-----  User primerykey from user table
  "title": "Mobile",
  "desc": "good quality",
  "quantity": "1000",
  "price": "1000/piece",
  "post_date": "12-06-2015",
  "offer_start": "12-06-2015",
  "offer_end": "12-07-2015",
  "loc_lat": 12.34,
  "loc_long": 23.43,
  "photo_url": [
    {
      "url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com"
    }
  ],
  "video_url": [
    {
      "url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com"
    }
  ]
}
}
 ]
```

Comment: See https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-06-23-geofire-two-point-oh.html for info on how to query for location.

Comment: Thanks, I have gone through Firebase doc for structuring data but it would be nice if you can explain how a complex schema can be created using firebase. [Example:- University management or Employee management  system, e-com site]. Example of members and group in the doc does not explain all basic concepts of database. For a SQL guy its difficult to understand. I  hope many people are looking for such explaination.